# How to save Password and Salt in shiro.ini

Tags: java, ini, salt, shiro

currently I work with Shiro to create an authenticated and authorized connection between server and client.
For now I don't have a special realm and only use the shiro.ini to save all my test users.
My question now is if there is a possibility to save the salt for each user in the shiro.ini or do I have to create a seperate database as a realm?

So is there the chance to save it somehow like this within the .ini?

```
[users]
*username* = *hashed Password*, *salt*, *roles
```

I actually do not really understand how or where I can save a random salt for each user.

My current understanding is that the 'hashed Password' in the ini is the final comparison value, for the incoming token containing a password that firstly has to be hashed with the user specific salt.